# Multiple Prepared statements in PHP with MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want to make two prepared statements, one right after the other in PHP with MySQLi. I am a novice at PHP and MySQLi so I don't know whether I should close the statement, close the database connection, put all of the code in a function, or just have code not inside a function.

Basically, I just want to insert a record into one table and then insert the same record into another table using MySQLi.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Directly off the mysqli page: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php

```
<?PHP
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');

/* set autocommit to off */
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

/* Insert some values */
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('DEU', 'Bavarian', 'F', 11.2)");
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('DEU', 'Bavarian', 'F', 11.2)");

/* commit transaction */
$mysqli->commit();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

*Edit with prepared statements for "non-sane" action:

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "");
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');

/* set autocommit to off */
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

$stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl1 (id, intro) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl2 (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)");

$str1 = 'abc';
$str2 = 'efg';
$str3 = 'hij';
$str4 = 'klm';

$stmt1->bind_param('ss', $str1, $str2);
$stmt2->bind_param('ss', $str3,$str4);

$stmt1->execute();
$stmt2->execute();

/* commit and set autocommit to on */
$mysqli->autocommit(true);
```

Comment: I see no prepared statements here

Comment: yea I can see how to do it without prepared statements, but I don't know how to deal with the over head of prepared statements, but thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

> whether I should close the statement

No.

> close the database connection

No.

> put all of the code in a function

Preferably, if you have an idea what functions are and how to use them.

BTW, inserting the same data twice makes no sense. You have to link data, not double it.

Comment: so right after I execute my first prepared statement can I go about preparing and executing my second one?

Comment: No. Is I said above, it makes no sense. You already inserted your data, no need to insert it again

Comment: it's not the exact same data, so I do need to insert it again

Comment: How come it is not exact the same if you need to insert it *again*?

Comment: i just want to do an insert after another insert

Comment: Why shouldnt he? An action may require inserts to two different tables.

Comment: Nope, no sane action would require that

Comment: Without being provocative, how would you suggest handling a form where one might insert an entity and its relationship as selected from a multi select?

Comment: @CharlesWeiss as is:  nsert an entity and its relationship, NOT entity twice

Answer (score 0):

There are several different questions in here and I can try to answer all of the remaining ones. The answer by RumpRanger, with the edits from Dharman, shows the details of how to do the prepared statements.

You want to keep the database connection open while you do all your queries. You rarely ever want or need to close a connection; it will close automatically when the script finishes execution. When I code in PHP I only close the connection in scripts where something complex is going to happen after the connection is needed. Even this type of use, however, has become less beneficial over time because newer versions of PHP have built-in optimization and clean up certain variables automatically if they see they are not used later in a script, and destruction of objects associated with a MySQL connection will close the connection automatically.

Whether or not to put the code in a function depends on whether or not you intend to generalize or abstract what you are doing in the query. If you anticipate needing to do the same query but with different parameters, multiple times from multiple places in your code, then put it in a function. If you know this isn't going to be the case, then just write the code out.