# How to run multiple SQL queries at the same time?

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I have two tables, one `comment` and the other `pendingcomment`. When I copy the data of the `pendingcomment` in the `comment` table, I want that data to be deleted from the `pendingcomment` table.

I was thinking of using `mysqli_multi_query` to do it, but I don't know how to use it. Is there any way to execute multiple queries as one in PHP?

Comment: Security concerns aside, this question is off-topic typo because it does not have a delimiting semicolon between queries.  Otherwise it would work (insecurely/unstably).  As for earlier pages which demonstrate multiple prepared statements in a transaction: [Multiple Prepared statements in PHP with MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9640396/2943403)

Comment: @mickmackusa I have edited the question and submitted it for review.

Comment: The resolving advice remains the same.  This question can be a signpost for the other page, your advice is very much suitable on the other page.

Answer (score 2):

When executing queries you need to execute them one after another using prepared statements. This is how it should be done properly:

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'test');
$conn->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

$id = $_GET['id'];

// begin atomic transaction
$stmt = $conn->begin_transaction();

// prepare statement for insert
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO comment (blogid, name, email, subject, message, date) SELECT blogid, name, email, subject, message, date FROM pendingcomment WHERE id= ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmt->execute();

// prepare statement for delete
$stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM pendingcomment WHERE id=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmt->execute();

// commit transaction
$conn->commit();
```

You must use transactions to make the two statements operate as a single DB operation. A transaction ensures atomicity of the operations as long as your DB engine is InnoDB or a similar transaction engine. MyISAM is not. **Remember to enable mysqli error reporting** or it won't work.

And a very important warning:

***NEVER USE `mysqli_multi_query()`!!!***

This function is extremely unsafe and causes a lot more problems than it solves. In fact, it doesn't solve any problems, it just creates more. **You can't run queries at the same time from PHP!** It is impossible to do so without threading or parallelization. If you need something like this then you can check out [Swoole](https://www.swoole.co.uk/) or [ReactPHP](https://reactphp.org/) but it's probably not needed in your case.