# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 ... near 'INSERT INTO `ps_kfasupply_warehouse_receipt_detail` (`id_ware...' at line 6

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

We have a module which is working fine PrestaShop 1.6.1.23 - PHP 7.1
But it is throwing this error on PrestaShop 1.7.8.9 and 8.1.2 (PHP 7.4 & 8.1).

**This is the error in PS1.7:**

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `ps_kfasupply_warehouse_receipt_detail` (`id_warehou' at line 6

```
INSERT INTO `ps_kfasupply_warehouse_receipt_detail`
(`id_warehouse_receipt`, `row_number`, `name`, `quantity`, `sales_return_quantity`, `barcode`, `supplier_reference`, `package_type`, `quantity_per_package`, `description`)
VALUES(1, '1', 'test1', 10, 0, '', '', '', 0, '');

INSERT INTO `ps_kfasupply_warehouse_receipt_detail`
(`id_warehouse_receipt`, `row_number`, `name`, `quantity`, `sales_return_quantity`, `barcode`, `supplier_reference`, `package_type`, `quantity_per_package`, `description`)
VALUES(1, '2', 'test2', 20, 0, '', '', '', 0, '');
```

**This is the error in PS8.1:**

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `ps_kfasupply_warehouse_receipt_detail` (`id_ware...' at line 6

(The query is the same: 2 INSERTs).

---

**More information:**

This is a form for a warehouse receipt that has some fields like Supplier and Brands and Invoice info's and also has a list of items. The form submits when there is no item or even when there is only 1 item. But when I add 2 or more items, I get these errors.

The way it is handled is in a foreach the queries for all the warehouse items (Insert) are created and added into a string. Then the string is executed at the end.

When I manually test this whole query in phpMyAdmin, it works.

---

How can I solve this?

Comment: Depending on how you run the SQL, depends if it allows multiple SQL statements. But there are alternative ways of doing this (an array of queries for example) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67256795/how-to-run-multiple-sql-queries-at-the-same-time

Comment: There is no mysql version 10.x,  that's MariaDB. Even the 2nd error message explicitly says MariaDB.

Comment: Multiple statement queries had been disabled for security reason starting from PS 1.7.8.8 - See https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/29586
Therefore you'll need to adjust the module code accordingly